# ubuntu terminal: showing blank

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

I just run the following command to set the path while installing laravel

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After this command nothing is shown on ubuntu terminal. just cursor is blinking.
What to do?

Comment: can you post the contents of the bashrc file ?

Comment: my terminal not working. its showing only cursor. no command is running. No $ symbol. just nothing. I restarted my system, still the same problem.

Comment: the problem lies in your .bashrc file. Edit it using a text editor and remove the lines you added, save it, open then a terminal to see if it wokred

Comment: Ctrl+C is working. the problem was crashing of previous command.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of ~/.bashrc file is to provide a place where you can set up variables, functions and aliases, define your prompt and define other settings that you want to use every start you open a new terminal window.

Depending on what contains inside your .bashrc file, it may give some output or nothing at all.

If you want to check whether the `bin` directory of laravel is added to PATH variable or not, you can check it by running `echo $PATH`.